# Requiring a Session for use in tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, protractor, e2e-testing

*What I'd like to do:* Have an end-to-end (protractor) test access an **authorized** section of the application.

*Pain:* Automated tests attempt to log in, but then redirected to the login page because **access token not found**.

Some session code from *vendor.js* file:

```
angular.module('Session', ['ngCookies'])
.factory('Session', ['$cookies',
    function($cookies) {
        var Session = {
            // Session code
        }
    })
);
```

My best guess, is to *require* the 'Session' from within a protractor test. If this is what I'm missing, how can I require the session session module alone? I've always required entire files rather than parts of it. Here's hoping I'm in the right direction.

```
var my_session = require(./vendor.js);
```